# ResetPassword functionality in Spring Security UI plugin

Tags: grails, spring-security, reset-password

I am new to grails.
I create a grails application in netbeans 7.2.1.
I am using grails-1.3.4.

I need to implement ForgotPassword functionality.
So for that I download and install the dependencies of Spring Security UI plugin and install this plugin too.
I am able to register user, also able to verify it through email.

Now I am using **ForgotPassword** functionality of this plugin and It is sending mail with the request token.
On clicking the link sent in the mail I am able to see the reset password form.
But when I entered correct password in both i.e. **New Password** and **Re-enter Password**.
Its just staying on the same page, not giving any error and no message is being displayed just stays on the ResetPassword form.

and password is not getting changed.

I have create User and Role domain class using s2-quickstart command and added an email field to User class.

**EDIT :**

When I click the reset password link mentioned in the mail I got reset password form but also sees an error message as in attached image

[image]
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably double-encoding the password. See the section "Password Encryption" in http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-spring-security-ui/docs/manual/guide/10%20Customization.html for the configuration setting for this.

Btw - you're new to Grails but using 1.3.4? You should be using 2.1.x or 2.2.x

Comment: Actually I am doing a project in grails for which I need to use 1.3.4

Comment: well... as stated in above documentation link i added `grails.plugins.springsecurity.ui.encodePassword = false` to Config.groovy but problem not solved

Answer (score 0):

Along the same lines as Burt's response, are you by any chance using multiple data sources?  If so, you may be running into [this issue](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPSPRINGSECURITYCORE-114).  The last comment on that page describes a possible workaround.